# SPFX propertyFieldCollectionData with FilePicker

Tags: spfx-webparts, react

I have been trying to get a FilePicker to work in the propertyFieldCollectionData without success

I have got an IconPicker to work using the below code

```
{ id: "icon",
  title: "Select Icon",
  type: this.customCollectionFieldType.custom,
  onCustomRender: (field, value, onUpdate, item, itemId, onError) => {
  return (
          React.createElement(IconPicker, {
              key: itemId,
              buttonLabel: "Select File",
              onChange: (iconName: string) => {
                   onUpdate(field.id, iconName);
                   return Event;
              },
              onSave: (iconName: string) => {
                   onUpdate(field.id, iconName);
                   return Event;
              }
             })
      );
  }},
```

but I cannot get FilePicker to work, and after extensive research i can't find any projects that have this functionality, so I am starting to think it is not possible...!

I would like a file picker so users can pick an image for each item in the propertyFieldCollectionData

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue and get filepicker to work in the collection data property, and thought I would post it for others to use if required

```
{ id: "image",
  title: "Select Image",
  type: this.customCollectionFieldType.custom,
  onCustomRender: (field, value, onUpdate, item, itemId, onError) => {
      return (
          React.createElement(FilePicker, {
              context: this.context,
              key: itemId,
              buttonLabel: "Select Image",                                                      
              onSave: (filePickerResult: IFilePickerResult[]) => {
                  onUpdate(field.id, filePickerResult[0].fileAbsoluteUrl);
              return Event;                                                     
                       }
              })
      );
  }},
```